# Cant access custom module through admin

Tags: php, magento

I have created a custom module in magento and I want it to be accessible by admin only.

The module structure is as follows:-
In **/app/code/local/Mage/Customerfriends**

**controllers/IndexController.php**

```
class Mage_Customerfriends_IndexController extends Mage_Adminhtml_Controller_Action
{
    public function exportAction()
    {        
        echo 'working';
    }
}
```

**etc/config.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <Mage_Customerfriends>
            <version>0.1.0</version>    <!-- Version number of your module -->
        </Mage_Customerfriends>
    </modules>
    <admin>
        <routers>
            <customerfriends>
                <use>admin</use>
                <args>
                    <module>Mage_Customerfriends</module>
                    <frontName>customerfriends</frontName>
                </args>
            </customerfriends>
        </routers>
    </admin> 
</config>
```

**app/etc/modules/Mage_Customerfriends.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"  encoding="UTF-8"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <Mage_Customerfriends>
            <active>true</active>
            <codePool>local</codePool>
        </Mage_Customerfriends>
    </modules>
</config>
```

Now when I am trying to access this controller I am getting 404 error.

Url is **example.com/index.php/admin/customerfriends/index/export/key/abcdef**

Comment: in magento admin the module is showing up in configuration ?

Comment: @n01ze yes its showing

Comment: Have you tried example.com/index.php/customerfriends/index/export ?